# gmdate() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given

Tags: php, date

Here is my try

```
$final_expiry_date = gmdate("Y-m-d", $unix_date_exp);
```

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  gmdate() expects parameter 2 to
>   be integer, float given
>
> Filename:
>   controllers/PermissionSettingController.php
>
> Line Number: 83

Here My Code
[image]

Comment: `$unix_date_exp` needs to be either `(int)$unix_date_exp`, or `ceil($unix_date_exp)` or `floor($unix_date_exp)`,Please add code in question, not as an image. it's hard to check as well as copy-paste code and try it at our end is nearly impossible.

Comment: What about the simple `(int)$unix_date_exp`  ?

Comment: no.. it not working, its is import date format column excel to database..

Answer (score 0):

You can give [floor](https://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) or [ceil](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round off value for `$unix_date_exp`.

```
$unix_date_exp = floor($unix_date_exp); // or ceil($unix_date_exp);
```

As `gmdate` is expecting value to be integer, but by your calculation value will be `float`, so you need to round it off to nearest `integer` by doing `floor` or `ceil` to value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$excel_date_exp` (from which your `$unix_date_exp` is calcualted )is `0.0` (float), youare passing it in to the function that expects and integer. You have 2 paossible options here:

a) set your `$excel_date_exp = 0` (int)

b) convert it before passing in to the function: `$final_expiry_date = gmdate("Y-m-d", (int)$unix_date_exp);`

or `$final_expiry_date = gmdate("Y-m-d", floor($unix_date_exp));` - since yor calculations will not add any decimals.